# Python namedtuple in a boolean context

Tags: python, boolean, namedtuple

When a Python tuple is used in a boolean context, it is considered `True` if and only if it is not empty.

Does the same apply to instances of `collections.namedtuple`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, yes, but you can't create an empty instance of any useful namedtuple, because when you create a namedtuple type, you have to specify the number of elements up front.  So the only way you can have an empty namedtuple is to have a namedtuple type that is always empty, in which case it serves no purpose.

Comment: So, to clarify, useful `namedtuple`s are always truthy?

Comment: @PaulBaker: Yes, because they're always nonempty.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but in general you probably won't ever see it happen, since you specify names for each value in the `namedtuple`. Specifying no names would allow you to create an empty tuple type, but such a type would not be very useful, since its instances will *always* be empty:

```
>>> empty = collections.namedtuple("empty", [])
>>> empty()
empty()
>>> bool(empty())
False
```

Answer (score 3):

**Yes.** You can see this by inspecting a named tuple class.

One way to do so is to view a named tuple class's source code, using `._source` in Python 3.3 or later, or the `verbose=True` option to `namedtuple()`. You will see that named tuples extend `tuple`, and don't override the `__nonzero__()` or `__len__()` methods. This means they use the same logic as `tuple`, like you thought.

You can also check a named tuple class's `__nonzero__` and `__len__` attributes. You will see that it has no `__nonzero__` attribute defined, and that the `__len__` attribute is the same as the one for `tuple`:

```
>>> A = namedtuple('A', ['x'])
>>> A.__len__ == tuple.__len__
True
```